# Metal Toolbar Icon Sizes

Tags: cocoa, macos, toolbar

I am trying to create rectangular metal toolbar icons for a mac app like the ones seen in Safari, but can't seem to find any information on the pixel size.

Human Interface Guidelines recommends that metal toolbar buttons should not exceed 19x19, but doesn't specify what the size of the icon should be if the user chooses "Use Small Size" when customizing the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

A quick screenshot of the Safari icons show 22 pixel height. I'd take the guidelines with a grain of salt at this point. The unity in this area seems to be pretty much gone. 22 is a nice height because it's the size of the toolbar so it looks clean in Safari. Do what looks best in your app.